# Не отображается фотография в ImageView

Tags: android, файлы, bitmap, камера, imageview

Почему не выводится фото в ImageView? Ни по uri, ни как bitmap, ни как drawable. Файл с фотографией существует. Подскажите в чем ошибка.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.out);

    DataInputStream in = null; 
    try { 
        in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(schet)); 
        Integer n = Integer.valueOf(in.readInt());
        in.close();
        File image = new File(imagesFolder + "face_" + n + ".jpg");
        Uri face = Uri.fromFile(image);
        mIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outImageView);
        mIV.setImageURI(face);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Button backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.outButton);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Result.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }
```

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Result" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Манифест добавьте. В логи ошибки какие выдаёт сей код?

Comment: Ошибок не выдает как бы..

Comment: в Bitmap пробовали загружать картинку? ширина\высота не нулевая у битмепа получается?

Comment: Нет, не нулевая

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку, она поможет избежать OOM в случае чего, а так же не придется писать свои извращения

```
File f = new File("path_to_file")
Picasso.with(context).load(f).into(imageView);
```

Подробней тут http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Не выводит все равно!   `File imagesFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/Faces");                        File image = new File(imagesFolder, "face_1.jpg");
   ImageView mIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outImageView);
   Context context = mIV.getContext();
   Picasso.with(context).load(image.getAbsolutePath()).into(mIV);`